# Animate counter from start to end value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put a counter on my site.
The following code works for very large numbers, but low numbers like 3 or 95.5 do not work. But it works with numbers over 1000.Where do you think the problem is with the JavaScript code written?
Thanks in advance for your guidance.

```js
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.count');
const speed = 200;
counters.forEach((counter) => {
  const updateCount = () => {
  const target = parseInt(counter.getAttribute('data-target'));
    const count = parseInt(counter.innerText);
    const increment = Math.trunc(target / speed);
    if (count < target) {
       counter.innerText = count + increment;
       setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
    } else {
       counter.innerText = target;
    }
  };
 updateCount();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="counter">
    <div class="counter--inner">
       <span>+</span>
       <span data-target="3" class="count">0</span>
       <span>Years</span>
    </div>
    <p>example1</p>                     
  </div>
  
  <div class="counter">
    <div class="counter--inner">
       <span>+</span>
       <span data-target="50000" class="count">0</span>
    </div>
    <p>example2</p>                     
  </div>
  
  <div class="counter">
    <div class="counter--inner">
      <span data-target="95" class="count">0</span>
      <span>%</span>
    </div>
    <p>example3</p>                     
  </div>
  
  <div class="counter">
    <div class="counter--inner">
       <span data-target="10000" class="count">0</span>
      <span>%</span>
    </div>
    <p>example4</p>                     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe try with Math.ceil

Answer (score 4):

## Animate *counter* using CSS only

**NOTICE:** missing Firefox support (2024.)

You can animate a CSS Var integer by defining a [@property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property) and by using `animation` property and CSS `counter` on the `::before/after` pseudo element:

```css
@property --from {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.counter {
  transition: --from 1s;
  counter-reset: int var(--from);
  animation: counter var(--time, 1000) forwards ease-in-out;
}

.counter::after {
  content: counter(int);
}

@keyframes counter {
  to {
    --from: var(--to, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<br>Count from 0 to 100
<br><span class="counter" style="--from:0; --to:100; --time:4s;"></span>
<br>You don't necessarily have to start at 0
<br><span class="counter" style="--from:1000; --to:2024; --time:4s;"></span>
<br>You can also count in reverse
<br><span class="counter" style="--from:9999; --to:0; --time:4s;"></span>
<br>or even to negative values
<br><span class="counter" style="--from:1000; --to:-1000; --time:4s;"></span>
<br>This one will not count
<br><span class="counter" style="--from:666; --to:666; --time:4s;"></span>
```

## Animate counter using JavaScript

> ***MDN Docs:*** The [Math.trunc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) function returns the integer part of a number by removing any fractional digits.

Therefore in `Math.trunc(target / 200)`
— `target` has to be at least `200` for you to finally get a `1`. But you always get a `0` and you try to do a `0 + 0`.

---

#### What not to do

- **Don't use `textContent` to grab values** from DOM Nodes on every loop iteration. Simply, increment an integer variable
- Never use `setTimeout/setInterval()` set at a small milliseconds value. Such will **clog the [main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread)**, and your application performance might suffer from it. Even worse if this operation happens for multiple elements on a single page.
- **Don't animate different counters at a different timing duration**.  A proper implementation would be to animate all counters during a constant time, going from `0`to`10` or from `0`to`9999999` should be *"animated"* during a **constant time duration** — for the user to perceive those visual clues/changes and make sense of it, for multiple *counter* elements.

#### Animate the range during a defined time period

Here's a bulletproof example on how to properly create animated counters using JavaScript:

- use the proper, more performant [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) (instead of setTimeout or setInterval) to not cog the main thread.
- use elements with `[data-counter]` attribute. The counter will consider `textContent` as the start value, and count to the end value which is stored in the actual `data-counter` attribute
- count either *up* or *down* — depending on the start/end values
- will not count if the *start* value equals the *end* value

```js
const ease = {
  linear: t => t,
  inOutQuad: t => t<.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t,
  // Find out more at: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
};

const counter = (EL) => {

  const duration = 4000; // Animate all counters equally for a better UX

  const start = parseInt(EL.textContent, 10); // Get start and end values
  const end = parseInt(EL.dataset.counter, 10); // PS: Use always the radix 10!

  if (start === end) return; // If equal values, stop here.

  const range = end - start; // Get the range
  let curr = start; // Set current at start position
  
  const timeStart = Date.now();

  const loop = () => {
    let elaps = Date.now() - timeStart;
    if (elaps > duration) elaps = duration; // Stop the loop
    const norm = ease.inOutQuad(elaps / duration); // normalised value + easing
    const step = norm * range; // Calculate the value step
    curr = start + step; // Increment or Decrement current value
    EL.textContent = Math.trunc(curr); // Apply to UI as integer
    if (elaps < duration) requestAnimationFrame(loop); // Loop
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(loop); // Start the loop!
};

document.querySelectorAll("[data-counter]").forEach(counter);
```

```html
<br>Count from 0 to 10
<br><span data-counter="10">0</span>
<br>You don't necessarily have to start at 0
<br><span data-counter="2022">1000</span>
<br>You can also count in reverse
<br><span data-counter="0">9999</span>
<br>or even to negative values
<br><span data-counter="-1000">1000</span>
<br>This one will not count
<br><span data-counter="666">666</span>
<br>
<br>And for a better UX - all the counters finished simultaneously  during 4000ms
```

Comment: What if you wanted to ease the value?

Comment: @jos3ph_1205 instead of using a *normalized* `frac` that has range 0..1 like in: `const frac = elaps / duration;` - use instead an easing timing function like: `const frac = easeOutQuart(elaps / duration);` (would be also better to rename that variable to `t` instead of `frac` ;) ) You can find more easing functions online like i.e: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294 - See also this answer as example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77348741/383904

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Bujian !
I actually found a way to get the same effect using just CSS!
This helps too though

Comment: @jos3ph_1205 there's incomplete browser support ATM (2024. Firefox missing full support for CSS @property).

Comment: Yep, I've noticed that too. It's at 87% support across all browsers ATM though, so It should be fine I guess. We'll just have to wait on firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to increment zeroes.

```
const increment = Math.trunc(target / speed);
```

When your target is less than 200 (which is your hard-coded speed) it will return a 0.

`Math.trunc(3/200)` will be 0 because according to the MDN Web Docs:

> The Math.trunc() function returns the integer part of a number by removing any fractional digits.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

That's why it won't work on lower numbers than 200.

What you can do is remove the Math.trunc and increment those decimal values instead.