# How to make motion sinusoidal in canvas?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I wish to make the linear motion of a dot sinusoidal so that is slows to a stop at the edges and changes direction and speeds up on the middle. Here is my attempt.

```
let q = 51;
let x = 100;
let chang = 4;
let radiu = 20;
function motion(){
  requestAnimationFrame(motion);
  ctx3.beginPath();
  ctx3.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx3.fillRect(0,0,canvas3.width,canvas3.height);
  ctx3.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx3.arc(x * Math.sin(q), 100, radiu, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx3.fill();
  ctx3.closePath();
  if(x + radiu > 200 || x - radiu < 50 ){
    chang=-chang;
  }
  x += chang;
  q=+1.0;
  //q+=0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need a custom easing function like:

> *`f(t) = sin(t - PI / 2) * 0.5 + 0.5`*

that accepts a constant **time** `t` and returns the sine in decimal values from 0.0 to 1.0.
The `PI / 2` is used to start at -1.0 (instead of center `0`),  and `* 0.5 + 0.5` is used to convert the range `-1.0 .. 1.0` to `0.0 .. 1.0` (exclusive).

To retrieve the new `x` position: multiply the resulting *easeSin* value by the *xEnd* position you want to travel to, for the back and forth motion. (Account also for the radius to not pass the edges).

For the `t` time, instead of using a separate variable you could make use of the requestAnimationFrame's first argument *timeStamp*:

```js
const easeSin = (t) => Math.sin(t - Math.PI / 2) * 0.5 + 0.5;
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

// Circle properties:
const rad = 20;
let x = 0;
let y = 100;

const motion = (time) => {
  const ease = easeSin(time * 0.001); // retrieve the sine (0.0, 1.0)
  x = rad + ease * (300 - rad * 2);
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  requestAnimationFrame(motion);
};

motion();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the help. Exactly what I needed. Took me so long to not get it to work!

Comment: @ofey you're very welcome, glad it helped – PS: edited the answer to simplify the logic, and get better intuitive values from the easeSin function

Comment: Is easeSin() a built in function like Math.sin() or Math.cos() and would it be good enough to generate circular motion with the M.sin() being the vertical component and Math.con() the horizontal component? I have a button which successfully calls the motion() function. Also is  everything not supposed to be wrapped in the requestAnimationFrame()? But it is empty.

Comment: @ofey as you can see, `easeSin` is a function we created. It's not available by default from the JS's `Math` namespace. That's just an easing function that takes a linear number and returns a different value (sinusoid in that case). Here are some other common easing functions for additional reference: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294 No. What is supposed to be wrapped in the RAF loop is exactly the code that *is* wrapped. Basically the things you need for repainting the canvas. All the other functions or variables need to be defined outside of the loop, end eventually used in it.

Comment: @ofey another nice article I've found: https://www.febucci.com/2018/08/easing-functions/ that might help you to visually put in perspective the easing functions with nice animations.